# Error: method onEnable does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: java, android, overriding

I can't build my app because I've got this error:

```
Error:(117, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype.
```

I'm trying to do a class that extends from AppWidgetProvider and I can't override onEnable method

```
@Override
public void onEnable(Context context) {

    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Se ha activado onEnable");
    super.onEnabled(context);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10000 , createClockTickIntent(context));

}
```

Comment: Please show your class definition. Does it extend or implement something? Does parent class / interface has definition of `onEnable` method?

Answer (score 1):

To override method of super class you should use the same name of the method and parameters

```
 @Override
 public void onEnabled(Context context) {
  //your code
 }
```